# Implemnting a Trie Data structures problem from HackerRank using Python3

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a better code in python. I don't know where to start checking. I want to make sure that I do write a best practice code.

**This is the second problem in Hackerrank trie data structure:**

> Given **N** strings. Each string contains only lowercase letters from (both inclusive). The set of  strings is said to be **GOOD SET** if no string is **prefix** of another string else, it is **BAD SET**. (If two strings are identical, they are considered prefixes of each other.)
>
> For example, aab, abcde, aabcd is **BAD SET** because aab is prefix of aabcd.
>
> Print **GOOD SET** if it satisfies the problem requirement. 
>   Else, print **BAD SET** and the first string for which the condition fails.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> First line contains , the number of strings in the set. 
>   Then next  lines follow, where  line contains  string.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Output **GOOD SET** if the set is valid. 
>   Else, output **BAD SET** followed by the first string for which the condition fails.
>
> **Sample Input00**
>
> ```
> 7
> aab
> defgab
> abcde
> aabcde
> cedaaa
> bbbbbbbbbb
> jabjjjad
> ```
>
> **Sample Output00**
>
> ```
> BAD SET
> aabcde
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Sample Input01**
>
> ```
> 4
> aab
> aac
> aacghgh
> aabghgh
> ```
>
> **Sample Output01**
>
> ```
> BAD SET
> aacghgh
> ```

```
from sys import stdin

class Node:
    def __init__(self,char):
        self.character = char
        self.children = {}
        self.counter = 0
        self.end_word = False

class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node('*')

    def add(self,word):
        current = self.root
        fail = False
        for char in word:
            if char not in current.children:
                new_node = Node(char)
                current.children[char] = new_node
                current = new_node
                new_node.counter += 1

            else:
                current = current.children[char]
                current.counter += 1
                if current.end_word:
                    fail = True

        current.end_word = True
        # first word > second word : second word is prefix of first word
        if current.counter >=2:
            fail = True

        return fail

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tree = Trie()
    n = stdin.readlines()
    for i in n[1:]:
        i = i.strip()
        add_check_string = tree.add(i)
        if add_check_string:
            print("BAD SET")
            print(i)
            break
    if not add_check_string:
        print("GOOD SET")
```

Answer (score 1):

- You could run `autopep8` for minor style corrections (e.g. whitespaces).
- Naming variables correctly is always extremely important, especially in a dynamic language, without indications about object type:

  - Your `trie` is a `Trie`, not just a `tree`.
  - `n` sounds like an integer. It could be called `lines`.
  - `i` also sounds like an integer. It could be `line` or `word`.
- Using `for/else` [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9980752/6419007), you can refactor your main method without any flag.

---

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    trie = Trie()
    _header, *lines = stdin.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        word = line.strip()
        if trie.add(word):
            print("BAD SET")
            print(word)
            break
    else:
        print("GOOD SET")
```

---

- If you wish, you could replace the 3 last lines of `add` by `return fail or current.counter >= 2`

Answer (score 0):

I think the only change I would make is removing `node.counter`, and instead detecting if a previous word is a prefix of the current word by checking if `current.fail==True`.

Comment: Thank you for your raply. May I know Why did you mention taht there are Performance Issues?

Comment: oops, I combined 2 separate (and unrelated) questions in my head, and pulled out that you thought this was a bottleneck somehow. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of repetition in your `add` method. 
This can be simplified, ditching the `fail flag` to

```
def add_unless_prefix(self,word):
    current = self.root
    for char in word:
        if char not in current.children:
            current.children[char] = Node(char)

        current = current.children[char]
        current.counter += 1
        if current.end_word:
            return True

    current.end_word = True

    return current.counter >=2
```

This can be simplified a bit using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

```
if char not in current.children:
    current.children[char] = Node(char)

current = current.children[char]
```

can become `current = current.children.setdefault(char, Node(char))`

Comment: I also tried to remove the `fail` flag, but .... I failed. By returning early, you prevent `word` from being added to the `trie`. `return fail` was just some extra piece of information, not the main purpose of the `add` method. At the very least, your new method should be called differently, e.g. `add_unless_prefix`.

Comment: Oops, small bug. That was meant to be `return True`, signalling that it matches a prefix

Comment: It still doesn't add the word to the trie, though. Given the name of the class and method, it still sounds like a bug.

Comment: this isn't mean to be a complete Trie. This is meant to detect whether there is a prefix, so in the context of this HackerRank issue, this suffices.

Comment: Fine, then you should change the method name to make it clear.